# Error using module_invoke_all('requirements', 'runtime') in my custom module

Tags: 7

Why do I get

> Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
>
> Original
>
> Exception: theme() may not be called until all modules are loaded. in theme() (line 920 of C:\wamp\www\test\includes\theme.inc).
>
> Additional
>
> Exception: theme() may not be called until all modules are loaded. in theme() (line 920 of C:\wamp\www\test\includes\theme.inc).

when try to call

```
    module_invoke_all('requirements', 'runtime')
```

from my custom module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you have that line of code outside a function in your module. That doesn't work.

I have no idea what you are trying to do but you should at least move it into a hook, like hook_init() so that it's only executed when Drupal is fully bootstrapped.